# Testing async handler and subsequent changes on the page with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

What i have is the simple page where I have the "Reset Password" button and "Confirm" button by defaut. If you will press "Reset password" it will be fetched from the server and displayed where this button was in "TextInput". Aslo "Confirm" button become active after that.
Here is my component.

```
export default function App({ profileId, onClose }) {
  const [ resetPasswordIsPressed, setResetPasswordIsPressed ] = useState(false);
  const [ temporaryPassword, setTemporaryPassword ] = useState(null);
  const [ isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled ] = true;

  const handleUserUpdate = () => {
    handleChangePassword(false);
    onClose()
  }

  const handleChangePassword = async isPressed => {
    const tempPassword = await fetchPassword(isPressed, profileId);

    setTemporaryPassword(tempPassword);
    setResetPasswordIsPressed(isPressed);
    setIsButtonDisabled(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      { resetPasswordIsPressed ? (
        <TextInput 
        isDisabled
        testId='passwordInput'
        value={temporaryPassword}
        />
        ) : (
        <PasswrodResetButton 
          onClick={() => handleChangePassword(true)}
          text='PasswordReset'
        />
        )
      }
      
      <ConfirmButton isDisabled={isButtonDisabled} onClick={handleUserUpdate}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here is fetch function which is imported from separate file

```
const fetchPassword = async (isPressed, profileId) => {
  const getPassword = httpPost(userService, userendPoint);

  try {
    const {data} = await getPassword({
      data: {
        profileId
      }
    });

    const { tempPassword } = data;
    return tempPassword;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message)
  }
}
```

What i need is to test that after clicking "Reset Password" handler was called, after that the "Reset Password" button is not on the page anymore, the "TextInput" with fetched password IS on the page, and the confirm button become active. Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
describe('User handlers', () => {
 it('Should trigger reset password handler', async () => {
  const mockCallBack = jest.fn();
  const action = shallow(<PasswordResetButton onClick={mockCallBack}/>);

  action.simulate('click');
  await screen.findByTestId('passwordInput')
})
})
```

But got 'Unable to find and element by: [data-testid="passwordInput"]'

Answer (score 0):

You're rendering your 'action' separately from your App component, which makes it completely independent.

I can't see in your code what 'screen' is, but most likely it's your shallowly rendered `App` component, and this is exactly where you need to find your `<PasswordResetButton />` and click it.

If you were to add to your `<PasswordResetButton />` a `testid` like you did to `<TextInput />`, you'd be able to do something like this:

```js
it('Should trigger reset password handler', async () => {
  const action = await screen.findByTestId('#passwordResetButton');

  action.simulate('click');
  const passwordInput = await screen.findByTestId('passwordInput');

  expect(passwordInput).toHaveLength(1);
})
```

But again, I'm not sure what your `screen` variable is and what exactly `screen.findByTestId` does and returns.

Comment: Unfotunately that's not gonna work. I don't have to look for passwordResetBtn with await because it's allready rendered. And also I want to check the calling of MY fetch function, not fake function. In order to do that you should do something like that:
jest.mock('../foo-bar-baz', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('../foo-bar-baz');

  //Mock the default export and named export 'foo'
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    default: jest.fn(() => 'mocked baz'),
    foo: 'mocked foo',
  };
});
and after that use jest.spyOn. But I'm steel trying.

Comment: Can you show what "screen" is? Please add it to the original question.

You have to mock your 'fetchPassword' call, right. And your idea is correct, you can do that on top of your page before the import of your `<App />` component to the test file. This way when your `App` component is imported, it will import the mocked `fetchPassword` instead of a real one.